# Retrieve the texture coordinate under the mouse

Tags: qt4, textures, opengl-3, mouse-picking, qtopengl

I'm working with `Qt 4.8` and its `OpenGL` module, with the fixed pipeline and I have a sphere that was cubemapped,  with the tex coords for each cube face auto-generated by `OpenGL` via `glTexGenf` (R, S and T coordinates).

```
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
const GLenum textgt = GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP;
const GLfloat param = GL_REFLECTION_MAP;

glTexGenf( GL_S, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, param );
GLenum error = glGetError();
if(GL_NO_ERROR != error) { ... }

glTexGenf( GL_T, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, param );
error = glGetError();
if(GL_NO_ERROR != error) { ... }

glTexGenf( GL_R, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, param );
error = glGetError();
if(GL_NO_ERROR != error) { ... }

glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S );
glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T );
glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_GEN_R );
```

When clicking in the scene, I'm retrieving the vertex coordinates under the mouse cursor via `glReadPixels` and `gluUnProject`.

What I'm looking for now is a way to retrieve the  `texture coordinate` associated to that position. I didn't find anything regarding this topic, so I was wondering if there was a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching through the `OpenGL` specs, I found in the version `1.3` the formula used to compute the texel for a given vertex **[Chapter 2, Section 10, Part 4 - Generating Texture Coordinates]**.

Starting with an unit vector `u` that goes from the origin to the vertex *in eye coordinates* and having `n` as the normal for that vertex *in eye coordinates*, we first need to calculate the *reflection vector*, `r`:

```
r = u - 2nT(nu)
```

Then, the `S`, `T` and `R` coordinates we're looking for will be

```
rx, ry, rz
```

respectively.

Also, [there's a web](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_glTexGen) that "translates" the formula to pseudocode. I'll post here the relevant part for `GL_REFLECTION_MAP`, in case the page is unavaliable:

```
 for(i=0; i<total; i++)
 {
   myEyeVertex = MatrixTimesVector(ModelviewMatrix, myVertex[i]);
   myEyeVertex = Normalize(myEyeVertex);
   myEyeNormal = VectorTimesMatrix(myNormal[i], InverseModelviewMatrix);
   dotResult = 2.0 * dot3D(myEyeVertex, myEyeNormal);
   //I am emphasizing that we write to s and t and r. Used to sample a cubemap.
   myTexCoord[i].s = myEyeVertex.x - myEyeNormal.x * dotResult;
   myTexCoord[i].t = myEyeVertex.y - myEyeNormal.y * dotResult;
   myTexCoord[i].r = myEyeVertex.z - myEyeNormal.z * dotResult;
 }
```